# How do I get the URLs out of an HTML file?

Tags: url, grep

I need to get a long list of valid URLs for testing my DNS server.  I found a web page that has a ton of links in it that would probably yield quite a lot of good links (http://www.cse.psu.edu/~groenvel/urls.html), and I figured that the easiest way to do this would be to download the HTML file and simply grep for the URLs.  However, I can't get it to list out my results with only the link.

I know there are lots of ways to do this. I'm not picky how it's done.

Given the URL above, I want a list of all of the URLs (one per line) like this:

> http://www.cse.psu.edu/~groenvel/
>   http://www.acard.com/
>   http://www.acer.com/
>   ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Method 1

**Step1:**

```
wget "http://www.cse.psu.edu/~groenvel/urls.html"
```

**Step2:**

```
perl -0ne 'print "$1\n" while (/a href=\"(.*?)\">.*?<\/a>/igs)' /PATH_TO_YOUR/urls.html | grep 'http://' > /PATH_TO_YOUR/urls.txt
```

Just replace the "**/PATH_TO_YOUR/**" with your filepath. This would yield a text file with only urls.

### Method 2

If you have lynx installed you could simply do this in 1 step:

**Step1:**

```
lynx --dump http://www.cse.psu.edu/~groenvel/urls.html | awk '/(http|https):\/\// {print $2}' > /PATH_TO_YOUR/urls.txt
```

### Method 3

Using curl:

**Step1**

```
curl http://www.cse.psu.edu/~groenvel/urls.html 2>&1 | egrep -o  "(http|https):.*\">" | awk  'BEGIN {FS="\""};{print $1}' > /PATH_TO_YOUR/urls.txt
```

### Method 4

Using wget:

```
wget -qO- http://www.cse.psu.edu/~groenvel/urls.html 2>&1 | egrep -o  "(http|https):.*\">" | awk  'BEGIN {FS="\""};{print $1}' > /PATH_TO_YOUR/urls.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

you need wget, grep, sed.
I will try a solution and update my post later.

Update:

```
wget [the_url];

cat urls.html | egrep -i '<a href=".*">' | sed -e 's/.*<A HREF="\(.*\)">.*/\1/i'
```